# Unassigned variable in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just started learning Unity 2D with the "How to make a 2D game" course from Brackeys on YouTube about 3 hrs ago. I'm using Unity 2018.4.1f1 on Ubuntu 18.04, and because JS is not supported in my version so I have to use C# instead. But I've encountered this error on the third video: The variable mainCam of GameSetup has not been assigned. This is my code in C#:

GameSetup.cs

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameSetup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera mainCam;

    public BoxCollider2D topWall, bottomWall, leftWall, rightWall;

    public Transform Player1, Player2;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // topWall = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        // mainCam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        // If I uncomment this, there would be a new error: There is no 'Camera' attached to '_GM' game object, but a script is trying to access it.
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Move each wall to its edge location
        topWall.size = new Vector2(mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width * 2.0f, 0f)).x, 1.0f);
        topWall.offset = new Vector2(0f, mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, Screen.width, 0f)).y + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

With the help of Google, I've add `rb2d.GetComponent<Rigibody2D>()` in `Start()` from the script of the second video under and prevent the error (there are no `Start()` in the video)

PlayerControls.cs

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{

    public KeyCode moveUp, moveDown;

    public float speed = 10;

    private Rigidbody2D rb2d = new Rigidbody2D();
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(moveUp))
        {
            Vector3 v = rb2d.velocity;
            v.y = speed;
            rb2d.velocity = v;
            // rb2d.velocity.y = speed;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(moveDown))
        {
            Vector3 v = rb2d.velocity;
            v.y = speed * (-1);
            rb2d.velocity = v;
        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 v = rb2d.velocity;
            v.y = 0;
            rb2d.velocity = v;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix the bug in GameSetup.cs ? I've done exactly what said in the video, but only changed the language from JS to C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either assign it null:

```
public Camera mainCam = null;
```

But you are most likely missing to attach a camera object to it in the Unity3D editor. Check your inspector and make sure that whatever object that is using this script(GameSetup.cs) has a camera object assigned to its public variable.

[image: GameObject with public variables in the form of GameObjects]
Should look something like this. You have to drag and drop a camera object to the Gameobject.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's also partly my fault, I haven't played the video till the right part yet...